# Call, Bind, Apply Vs Passing The Reference Object As An Argument

Tags: javascript

Using call and bind is important when setting the value of `this` to the intended object. But what is the significance of using `this` instead of just passing the object as an argument to the function?

The question occured to me after seeing that `.bind` is not supported in IE9 and below, so I started passing the object as a parameter to the function I am calling. (I know I could use a shim for `bind` but that is not the question. The question is about the rationale behind using `this`.)

What is the purpose of the `this, call, apply, bind` syntax in Javascript and what was it a solution to? Wouldn't it be simpler to pass the object as a parameter both for cross-browser support and simplicity (since `this` is commonly misunderstood or forgotton to be set correctly in code)?

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) isn't limited to just the `thisArg`. You can set multiple arguments.

Comment: `this` is an important keyword in class based programming, where a class reference can access its own properties and methods. Javascript has elements of true Object oriented (class based) programming as well as functional programming

Comment: `this` is closely related to the object-oriented idea of *methods* -- i.e., functions that belong to (or run somehow in the context of) some owning object. Do we really *need* functions that can belong to objects? Of course not; some programming languages merely make it idiomatic.

Comment: @AndyRay I certainly agree that `this` is essential in object oriented Javascript since it is the only way to address the object from inside it but my question is about the difference between passing it to the method as an argument and accessing it through the `this` of the function.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, this technique used at some languages (like Delphi). But using one-argument-less is more convenient I guess. It is not a functional style, it is OOP style and we love it, right? :)